# Why is there a double point between section and subsection?

Tags: sectioning, subsection, format, numeration

**I have defined the following box:**

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,14pt,twoside,reqno]{extbook}
    \usepackage[tmargin=28mm,bmargin=28mm,lmargin=28mm,rmargin=28mm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts,amssymb,amstext,amsthm,mathpazo, xfp, latexsym}
    \usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    
    \definecolor{mygrey}{RGB}{99,99,99}
    
    \newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{mytheorem}[3][]{
        enhanced jigsaw,colback=white,colframe=mygrey,coltitle=mygrey
        ,
        fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
        sharp corners,
        detach title,
        leftrule=30mm,
        underlay unbroken and first={\node[below,text=white,font=\sffamily\bfseries,align=center]
            at ([xshift=-15mm,yshift=-1mm]interior.north west) {THEOREM\\\thetcbcounter};},
        breakable,pad at break=1mm,
        #1,
        code={\ifdefempty{\tcbtitletext}{}{\tcbset{before upper={\tcbtitle\par\medskip}}}},
    }
    
    
    \begin{document}
        
        \section{Test section}
        
        \begin{mytheorem}[title=Normal Sampling Distributions]
            \lipsum[1]
        \end{mytheorem}
        
        \begin{mytheorem}
            \lipsum[2]
        \end{mytheorem}
        
        \begin{mytheorem}[title=Test]
            \lipsum[3-5]
        \end{mytheorem}
        
    \end{document}
```

[image: The numbering of chapter.section.subsection is ok]

[image: But when I insert this definition in another document I get this result for the numbering of chapter.section.subsection:]

Why this double point between section and subsection?

I have these definitions in my code:

```
`% Section style definition
\titleformat{\section}[runin]
{\normalsize \bfseries}
{\color{black} \S \hspace{.6pt} \thesection}
{1ex}{\color{black}}[\quad]

% Subsection style definition
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]
{\normalsize \bfseries}
{\color{black} $ \bullet $ \thesubsection}
{1ex}{\color{black}}[\quad]

\renewcommand\thepart{\Roman{part}.}
\renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection\arabic{subsection}.}`\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
```

[image: This is the format that I've defined for subsections]

Comment: Off-topic: the option `tmargin=28mm,bmargin=28mm,lmargin=28mm,rmargin=28mm` may be written more succinctly as `margin=28mm`. Also, I'd replace `\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts,amssymb,amstext,amsthm,mathpazo, xfp, latexsym}` with `\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathpazo,xfp}`. Why? Easy:`amsfonts` is loaded automatically by `amssymb`, `amstext` is loaded by automatically by `amsmath`, and there is no conceivable valid reason for loading `latexsym` since the package was completely superseded by `amssymb` (and `amsfonts`) in 1994. Yes, that's nearly 30 years ago.

Comment: More on your code: You appear to provide two `\newcolorbox[...]{mytheorem}...` defintions; the second is incomplete. Please fix.

Answer (score 2):

You're adding the trailing periods to the `\the<counter>` commands. Don't.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,twoside,reqno]{extbook}
\usepackage[tmargin=28mm,bmargin=28mm,lmargin=28mm,rmargin=28mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathpazo,xfp}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{mygrey}{RGB}{99,99,99}

\titleformat{\section}[runin]
  {\normalsize \bfseries}
  {\color{black} \S \hspace{.6pt} \thesection.}
  {1ex}
  {\color{black}}
  [\quad]

% Subsection style definition
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]
  {\normalsize \bfseries}
  {\color{black}$\bullet$ \thesubsection.}
  {1ex}
  {\color{black}}
  [\quad]

\renewcommand\thepart{\Roman{part}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{mytheorem}[1][]{
  enhanced jigsaw,
  colback=white,
  colframe=mygrey,
  coltitle=mygrey,
  fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
  sharp corners,
  detach title,
  leftrule=30mm,
  underlay unbroken and first={
    \node[below,text=white,font=\sffamily\bfseries,align=center]
      at ([xshift=-15mm,yshift=-1mm]interior.north west) {THEOREM\\\thetcbcounter};
  },
  breakable,
  pad at break=1mm,
  #1,
  code={\ifdefempty{\tcbtitletext}{}{\tcbset{before upper={\tcbtitle\par\medskip}}}},
}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
Some text to show runin

\section{Test subsection}
Some text to show runin

\begin{mytheorem}[title=Normal Sampling Distributions]
    \lipsum[1][1-5]
\end{mytheorem}

\begin{mytheorem}
    \lipsum[2][1-5]
\end{mytheorem}

\begin{mytheorem}[title=Test]
    \lipsum[3][1-5]
\end{mytheorem}

\end{document}
```

As you see, the trailing period is added in `\titleformat`.

[image]

Notes: no newer document should load `latexsym`; `amstext` is loaded by `amsmath` and `amsfonts` by `amssymb`. With the October 2021 release of LaTeX, loading `xfp` is no longer necessary.

You were defining `mytheorem` with `[3][]`, which means one optional argument (empty value default) and two mandatory ones. I fixed it in `[1][]`.

Comment: Thanks, egreg.  I added the trailing period in \titleformat because I like it so. Outside my new boxes for Theorem, the result is correct (see the last image, that shows the format I´ve defined for the enumeration of chapter.section-subsection). Therefore, the problem with the duplication section..subsection is inside this box, and I don't know why happen it.